# Find the idle GPU in a multi-GPU machine

Tags: c++, cuda, multi-gpu

I have the following code running under cuda (Windows 10, VS 2015).

```
//Code for running on one or 2 gpu's
const unsigned __int64 MemOutputSize = (1i64 << 25)*64; //2GB
int deviceCount;
cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
unsigned long long* dBuffer[2];
for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
    cudaMalloc(&dBuffer[dev], MemOutputSize); 
    cudaMemset(dBuffer[dev], 0, MemOutputSize); 
}
for (int i=0; i < (1024*1024*1024); i++) {
    int dev = i % deviceCount;
    cudaSetDevice(dev);
    runKernel<<<NUM_BLOCK, NUM_THREADS>>>(i, dBuffer[dev]);
}
//Copy data from GPU buffers to main mem
//Merge buffers into one.
```

*It does not matter which GPU runs which part of the code.*

Normally I would run the code on the fastest GPU. But there **are** two GPU's so this way I can run the code on both, doubling my speed.
However when I run the code, the slowest GPU runs at 100%, whilst the fastest runs at 67%, which means that I only get a speedup of 2 x 67% = 133%. I want both GPU's to be much nearer 100% utilization all the time.

I get these percentages from **Task manager** (select Performance tab, compute_0). And no, FireFox or other GPU using procs are not running.

Is there a way to select the currently idle GPU in the for loop?
*This would enable me to select the fast GPU 60% of the time and the slower one 40% of the time, increasing my speed-up to 158%*

As per the cuda tag, I'm only concerned with NVidia cards (dual GTX 980 in fact).

The full (working) code is here:

```
// System includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>



// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// helper functions & utilities to work with CUDA
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>




#define NUM_BLOCKS    2048  //2^11
#define NUM_THREADS   128   //2^7   49-11-7 = 31

const unsigned __int64 MemOutputSize = (1i64 << 25) * 64;  // (__int64)(2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
//const unsigned __int64 MemOutputSize = 0_40000000; //(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);




/************************************************************************************************************/
/*************************             Build the lookup table           *************************************/
/*************************                                              *************************************/
/************************************************************************************************************/

__global__ static void SevenToFive(const unsigned __int64 input, void* doutput) {

    const unsigned int NRegs = 16;

    unsigned __int64 Y[NRegs];
    // A cell looks like this:
    //   BCD   123
    //   AxA   405
    //   BCD   678
    // we're using half-adder logic to store the 1, 2 and 4's count in 3 bitplanes.
    const unsigned __int64 MaskR2 =  0x0303030303030303; //Keep the rightmost 2 rows.
    const unsigned __int64 MaskR1 =  0x0101010101010101; //Keep the rightmost row.
    const unsigned __int64 MaskL6 = (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF & (~MaskR2));
    const unsigned __int64 MaskL7 = (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF & (~MaskR1));
    //const unsigned __int64 AllOn =   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    const unsigned __int64 Mask5x5 = 0x007C7C7C7C7C0000;  //Both masks use the Q layout, because the input is transformed
    const unsigned __int64 Mask3x3 = 0x0000383838000000;  //to Q in the Y[0] register.
                                                          //const unsigned __int64 Mask6x4 = 0x00007E7E7E7E0000;  //Both masks use the Q layout, because the input is transformed
                                                          //const unsigned __int64 Mask4x2 = 0x0000003C3C000000;  //to Q in the Y[0] register.

    Y[14] = threadIdx.x;//*/   Y[14] = 127;  /*debug*/  7 bits
    Y[13] = blockIdx.x;//*/  Y[13] = 2047; /*debug*/ 11 bits

    //__int64 input2 = -1;
    //Put 7x7 input into Y15.
    //The top line (least significant) and left most line will be empty (lsb of every line).
    //when doing non-overlapping or's always use xor to make any errors stand out.
    //3+7+7+7+7 = 31 bits
    Y[15] = (input & 7) ^ (((input >> 3) & 127) << 4) ^ (((input >> 10) & 127) << 12) ^ (((input >> 17) & 127) << 20) ^ (((input >> 24) & 127) << 28); //^ (((input >> 31) & 7) << 36);
                                                                                                                                                       //Y[15] = (input2 & 7) ^ (((input2 >> 3) & 127) << 4) ^ (((input2 >> 10) & 127) << 12) ^ (((input2 >> 17) & 127) << 20) ^ (((input2 >> 24) & 127) << 28); //^ (((input2 >> 31) & 7) << 36);
    Y[15] = Y[15] << (20);
    //Y[15] = 0;
    //31+7 = 38 bits
    Y[15] = Y[15] ^ Y[14]; //threadIdx.x;
                           //38 + 7 + 4 = 49 bits. This makes a total of 2^49
    Y[15] = Y[15] ^ ((Y[13] & 127) << 8) ^ (((Y[13] >> 7) & 15) << 16); //blockIdx.x


    //Y[15] = 0x070702000 >> 1; //Test with a glider traveling south
    //Y[15] = 0x01c0000; //Test with a blinker
    //Y[15] = 0x00c0800; //Test with a preblock

    //Y[15] = AllOn;//*input;
    Y[1] = 0;
    Y[4] = 0;
    Y[3] = 0;
    ///*debug*/Y[15] = 0x7F007F087F007F;//#######;0000000,#######,000#000,#######,0000000,####### : 4 lines with a little ward in the middle.
    //Y[04] = (Y[15] << 7) & 0x8080808080808080;
    //Y[15] = (Y[15] >> 1) & 0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F;
                                      //Y[3] = (Y[3] >> (64 - 16));           //vpsrldq xmm3,xmm3,16-4             //keep the bottom 2 rows of NW & shift them to the top
    Y[6] = (Y[1] >> (64 - 8));            //vpsrldq xmm6, xmm1, 16 - 2                //N5           keep the bottom 1 rows of N & shift them to the top.
    Y[1] = (Y[1] >> (64 - 16));           //vpsrldq xmm1,xmm1,16-4              //N3           keep the bottom 2 rows of N & shift them to the top.
    Y[2] = ((Y[4] >> 6) & MaskR2);        //vpsrlw xmm2,xmm4,14              //W6           keep the 2 rightmost columns of W
                                          //Y[3] = ((Y[3] >> 6) & MaskR2);        //vpsrlw xmm3,xmm3,14              //NW1          keep the 2 rightmost columns of NW
    Y[5] = (Y[15] << 16);                 //vpslldq xmm5,xmm15,4              //main3        remove the bottom 2 rows from main
    Y[7] = (Y[15] << 8);                  //vpslldq xmm7,xmm15,2              //main5        remove the bottom 1 row from main
    /*D3*/Y[14] = (Y[1] ^ Y[5]);              //vpxor xmm14, xmm1, xmm5              //***** ymm14 3 - D    2 rows N +14 rows main
    /*A5*/Y[13] = (Y[7] ^ Y[6]);              //vpxor xmm13, xmm7, xmm6        //***** ymm13 5 - A'   1 row N  +15 rows main   
                                              //We are now done with N, ymm1 and ymm6
    Y[1] = ((Y[2] >> 1) & MaskR1);        //vpsrlw xmm1,xmm2,1                                         //W7           remove an extra column from W
    Y[7] = ((Y[15] << 1) & MaskL7);       //                                      //main7        Shift main right
    Y[8] = ((Y[13] << 1) & MaskL7);       //                                      //main0+N0     Shift main+N1 right
    Y[9] = ((Y[14] << 1) & MaskL7);       //                                      //main2+N2     Shift mainn+N2 right
    /*C7*/Y[12] = (Y[7] ^ Y[1]);              //                                         //***** ymm12 7 - C Main7+W7
    Y[7] = ((Y[7] << 1) & MaskL7);        //                                      //main6       Shift main right
    /*B6*/Y[11] = (Y[7] ^ Y[2]);              //                                         //***** ymm11 6 - B' Main6+W6
    Y[10] = (Y[11] << 8);                 //                                        //main4+W4    Shift Main6W6 down
    Y[7] = (Y[3] >> 8);                   //                                        //NW4         Shift NW1 up (only one row)
    Y[6] = ((Y[6] << 2) & MaskL6);        //                                      //N4          Shift N3 right
    Y[10] = (Y[10] ^ Y[7]);               //                                       //main4+W4+NW4
    /*A4*/Y[10] = (Y[10] ^ Y[6]);             //                                         //***** ymm10 4 - A
    Y[1] = (Y[1] << 8);                   //                                        //W0          Shift W7 down 1 row
    Y[7] = ((Y[7] >> 1) & MaskR1);        //                                      //NW0         Shift NW4 left (keep only 1 pixel)
    Y[0] = (Y[8] ^ Y[1]);                 //                                       //main0+N0+W0
    /*X0*/Y[0] = (Y[0] ^ Y[7]);               //                                        //***** ymm0 0 - x
    Y[1] = (Y[2] << 16);                                                          //W1          Shift W down 2 rows
    Y[8] = ((Y[9] << 1) & MaskL6);                                              //main1+N1    Shift Main2N2 right 1 column
    Y[8] = (Y[8] ^ Y[1]);                                                        //main1+N1+W1 Combine with W
    /*B18*/Y[8] = (Y[8] ^ Y[3]);                                                        //**** ymm8 1 - B  Combine with the original NW
    Y[7] = ((Y[1] >> 1) & MaskR1);                                              //W2          Shift W1 left 1 column
    Y[5] = ((Y[3] >> 1) & MaskR1);                                              //NW2         Shift the original NW left 1 column
    Y[1] = (Y[7] ^ Y[5]);                                                        //W2+NW2      combine w2 & NW2
    /*C2*/Y[9] = (Y[1] ^ Y[9]);                                                        //**** ymm9 2 - C' main2+N2+W2+NW2
                                                                                                                                                                                  //Count the 1's & 2's
    Y[1] = (Y[12] ^ Y[9]);       //1's count of c
    Y[2] = (Y[12] & Y[9]);       //2's count of c
    Y[3] = (Y[10] ^ Y[13]);       //1's count of a
    Y[4] = (Y[10] & Y[13]);       //2's count of a
    Y[5] = (Y[8] ^ Y[11]);       //1's count of b
    Y[6] = (Y[8] & Y[11]);       //2's count of b
    Y[7] = (Y[14] ^ Y[15]);     //1's count of d
    Y[8] = (Y[14] & Y[15]);     //2's count of d
                                //Add the 1's together
    Y[10] = (Y[1] & Y[3]);       //2's count of CA
    Y[1] = (Y[1] ^ Y[3]);       //combined ones of CA
    Y[12] = (Y[5] & Y[7]);       //2's count of BD
    Y[5] = (Y[5] ^ Y[7]);        //combined ones of BD
    Y[14] = (Y[1] & Y[5]);       //2's count of CABD
    Y[1] = (Y[1] ^ Y[5]);        //final count of the 1's
                                 //now we need to add all the 2's together.
    Y[3] = (Y[2] & Y[4]);        //4's count of ca
    Y[2] = (Y[2] ^ Y[4]);        //2's count of ca
    Y[5] = (Y[6] & Y[8]);        //4's count of bd
    Y[6] = (Y[6] ^ Y[8]);        //2's count of bd
    Y[7] = (Y[10] & Y[12]);      //4's count of CABD
    Y[8] = (Y[10] ^ Y[12]);      //2's count of CABD
    Y[9] = (Y[2] & Y[6]);        //4's count of cabd
    Y[4] = (Y[2] ^ Y[6]);        //2's count of cabd
    Y[11] = (Y[8] & Y[14]);      //4's count of CABD+abcd
    Y[12] = (Y[8] ^ Y[14]);      //2's count of CABD+abcd
                                 //add all 4's
    Y[15] = (Y[3] | Y[5]);        //Saturated add of the 4's
    Y[13] = (Y[7] | Y[9]);
    Y[14] = (Y[11] | Y[15]);
    //add the 2's
    Y[2] = (Y[12] ^ Y[4]);
    //final add
    Y[4] = (Y[14] | Y[13]);
    //now we have all the counts.
    Y[14] = (Y[0] & Y[2]);       //All 2's stay the same
    Y[3] = (Y[2] & Y[1]);       //Y[3] hold's the 3 neighbors; i.e. the new births
    Y[14] = (Y[14] | Y[3]);       //The same + births = new pattern
    Y[15] = (Y[14] & (~Y[4]));   //but subtract the 4+ neighbors
                                 //Now extract the 5x5 resulting block as well as the 3x3 input block
    Y[6] = (Y[15] & Mask5x5);  //get the output 5x5
    Y[4] = (Y[0] & Mask3x3);   //and the input 3x3
                               //Translate the 5x5 block into a linear number.
                               //Mask5x5 = 0x003E3E3E3E3E0000;  //Both masks use the Q layout, because the input is transformed
                               //Mask3x3 = 0x00001C1C1C000000;  //to Q in the Y[0] register.
                               //      ----1------            ------2------                 -------- 3------                          ----- 4------                      ------ 6-----
    Y[5] = ((Y[6] & 0x7C0000) >> (10 + 8)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7C000000) >> (10 + 16 - 5)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7C00000000) >> (10 + 24 - 10)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7C0000000000) >> (10 + 32 - 15)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7C000000000000) >> (10 + 40 - 20));
    Y[3] =                                   ((Y[4] & 0x38000000) >> (11 + 16))     | ((Y[4] & 0x3800000000) >> (11 + 24 - 3))  | ((Y[4] & 0x380000000000) >> (11 + 32 - 6));
    //                        Mask6x4 = 0x00007E7E7E7E0000;  //Both masks use the Q layout, because the input is transformed
    //                        Mask4x2 = 0x0000003C3C000000;  //to Q in the Y[0] register.
    //Y[5] = ((Y[6] & 0x7E0000) >> (9 + 8)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7E000000) >> (9 + 16 - 6)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7E00000000) >> (9 + 24 - 12)) | ((Y[6] & 0x7E0000000000) >> (9 + 32 - 18));
    //Y[3] = ((Y[4] & 0x3C000000) >> (18 + 8)) | ((Y[4] & 0x3C00000000) >> (18 + 16 - 4));
    //Y[15] is the output block where the data must be stored.
    //Every block = 256 / 8 = 64 bytes = 
    Y[5] = Y[5] * 64;
    //Y[3] is the inner 2x8 block, holding 8 bits, a number from 0 - 255. The upper 3 bits denote the dword to store the data in. The lower 5 bits are a shift mask denoting which bit to flip.
    //
    Y[4] = (1i64 << (Y[3] & 31i64)); //or mask.
    Y[3] = (Y[3] >> 5) * 4; //dword offset  //8*4 = 32 bits
    Y[5] = Y[5] | Y[3];
    //** remove this line!
    //Y[5] = Y[5] & ((MemOutputSize)-1); //mask at 512MB, because we don't have more memory.
                                       //** remove the above line !
    Y[5] = Y[5] + (unsigned __int64)doutput;
    /*debug*/atomicOr((unsigned int *)Y[5], (unsigned int)Y[4]);
}





void printDevProp(cudaDeviceProp devProp)
{
    printf("%s\n", devProp.name);
    printf("Major revision number:         %d\n", devProp.major);
    printf("Minor revision number:         %d\n", devProp.minor);
    printf("Total global memory:           %zu", devProp.totalGlobalMem);
    printf(" bytes\n");
    printf("Number of multiprocessors:     %d\n", devProp.multiProcessorCount);
    printf("Total amount of shared memory per block: %zu\n", devProp.sharedMemPerBlock);
    printf("Total registers per block:     %d\n", devProp.regsPerBlock);
    printf("Warp size:                     %d\n", devProp.warpSize);
    printf("Maximum memory pitch:          %zu\n", devProp.memPitch);
    printf("Total amount of constant memory:         %zu\n", devProp.totalConstMem);
    return;
}

unsigned long long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
    status.dwLength = sizeof(status);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&status);
    return status.ullTotalPhys;
}


#define filename "lookuptable5to3_doublecheckA.bin"

// Start the main CUDA Sample here
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("CUDA Lookup table 5x5->3x3 dual GPU version\n");
    int deviceCount;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
    printf("Device count is %i, ", deviceCount);
    printf("Available RAM = %lliGiB\n", (getTotalSystemMemory() >> 30i64));
    if (deviceCount > 2) { deviceCount = 2; }
    // This will pick the best possible CUDA capable device
    int dev1 = findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);
    cudaDeviceProp dp;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&dp, dev1));
    printDevProp(dp);

    //float *dinput = NULL;
    unsigned long long int* dGPUoutput[2];
    for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
        dGPUoutput[dev] = NULL;
    }
    //clock_t *dtimer = NULL;

    //clock_t timer[NUM_BLOCKS * 2];
    //float input[NUM_THREADS * 2];

    //for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS * 2; i++)
    //{
    //    input[i] = (float)i;
    //}

    //unsigned __int64 a = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    //unsigned __int64 b;

    //SevenToFive(&a, &b);

    //checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dinput, sizeof(float) * NUM_THREADS * 2));


    //checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dinput, input, sizeof(float) * NUM_THREADS * 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //timedReduction<<<NUM_BLOCKS, NUM_THREADS, sizeof(float) * 2 *NUM_THREADS>>>(dinput, doutput, dtimer);
    char* dest[2];
    char* outputdest;
    outputdest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MemOutputSize);
    if (outputdest == NULL) { printf("Out of memory"); getch(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    //test write
    //printf("test write of data\n");
    //std::ofstream outputFile;
    //outputFile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary);
    ///*debug*/outputFile.write(dest, MemOutputSize);
    //outputFile.close();
    printf("Start computing\n");
    //DebugSevenToFive((unsigned long long int)-1, NULL); //just a place to check if needed.
    //getch();
    for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
        cudaSetDevice(dev);
        /*debug*/checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&dGPUoutput[dev], sizeof(char) * MemOutputSize));
        /*debug*/checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(dGPUoutput[dev], 0, sizeof(char) * MemOutputSize));
        dest[dev] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MemOutputSize);
        if (dest[dev] == NULL) { printf("Out of memory"); getch(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    }
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //getch();
    //we need to repeat this 2^31 times.  31=5+6+20
    try {
        for (int k = 0; k < 64; k++) {  //2^6
            printf("%i of 64 ", k + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {  //2^5
                printf(".");
                for (int q = 0; q < 1024; q++) {
                    printf("%4i\b\b\b\b", 1023 - q);
                    for (int i = 0; i < (/*1024 **/ 1024); i++) {  //2^20
                     //__global__ static void SevenToFiveCount(const unsigned __int64 input, void* doutput) 
                        ///*debug*/SevenToFiveCount << <NUM_BLOCKS, NUM_THREADS >> > (i + (q * 1024) + (j * 1024 * 1024) + (k * 1024 * 1024 * 32), doutput);  //256K, need to run this code 2GB times.
                        int dev = i % deviceCount;
                        cudaSetDevice(dev);

                        SevenToFive<<<NUM_BLOCKS, NUM_THREADS>>> (i + (q * 1024) + (j * 1024 * 1024) + (k * 1024 * 1024 * 32), dGPUoutput[dev]);  //256K, need to run this code 2GB times.
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("-");
            for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
                cudaSetDevice(dev);
                checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
                /*debug*/checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dest[dev], dGPUoutput[dev], sizeof(char) * MemOutputSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
            }
            for (__int64 i = 0; i < MemOutputSize * sizeof(char); i++) {
                outputdest[i] = dest[0][i];
                for (int dev = 1; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
                    outputdest[i] |= dest[dev][i];
                }
            }
            std::ofstream outputFile;
            outputFile.open(filename, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary);
            outputFile.write(outputdest, MemOutputSize);
            outputFile.close();
            printf("W  \n");   
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        printf("\nDone computing\n");


        auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Millisecs used " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count() << "ms\n";

        int check = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 4); i++) {
            check |= outputdest[i];
        }
        if (check == 0) { printf("Error: nothing happened"); getch(); for (;;) {} }
        else { printf("all ok"); getch(); }

        //checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(dinput));
        for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
            cudaFree(dGPUoutput[dev]);
        }

        free(outputdest);
        outputdest = NULL;
        for (int dev = 0; dev < deviceCount; dev++) {
            free(dest[dev]);
            dest[dev] = NULL;
        }


        getch();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    catch (const std::exception& e) //catch all exceptions
    {
        printf("Oops, an error happened. Here are the details:\n");
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        printf("\nPress any key\n");
        getch();
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Are you concerned about systems where there might be a mix of AMD and NVidia-based GPUs?

Comment: You can select an idle GPU by launching a cuda event after each kernel call, and check if either event has triggered before issuing your next kernel.  If no events have triggered, then dispatch the kernel to whatever GPU you wish (e.g. round-robin, as you are doing), and re-issue the event.   You'll need one event for each GPU.  But I'm not sure any of this would have any meaningful effect if you are launching kernels back-to-back with no synchronization.  Something doesn't add up.

Comment: If you distribute an equal number of kernels to each GPU, then a slower GPU will presumably dictate the overall computation time, but this isn't really observable on-the-fly if you are issuing kernels back-to-back.  At any given point as you are issuing the first few thousand kernels, both GPUs are going to appear to be busy all the time.

Comment: I've copy-pasted full working code. The only sync I'm doing is lots of `atomicOr` calls.

Comment: Your loop is never going to witness or show a "currently idle" GPU.  You should think carefully about asynchronous kernel execution, or else run your code with a profiler to understand the timeline.  I think what you want is to apportion kernel launches to GPUs proportional to their observed speed.  Faster GPUs get more kernel launches dispatched to them. For this you would need to build a rate monitor that can give you useful info even when both GPUs are continuously busy.  It should be doable, but it's not a trivial one-liner addition to your for-loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, your diagnosis makes no sense. If in the "steady state" with a large number of enqueued kernels in the default stream on both devices (which is what your loop does),  your performance metric shows 100% utilization on the "slow" device and 67% on the "fast", then that  means a single kernel doesn't have enough parallel work to occupy the "faster" (read larger) device to 100%. It isn't then a matter of finding idle time on the "fast" device to run more work, because there won't be any idle time to find, only idle GPU resources. Very different thing

Answer (score -2):

(this doesn't fit into a comment, sorry)

Prepare a solver, feed it all GPUs instantanous or average performances for last several seconds as variables. Minimize total time per N kernels or maximize 1 kernel / average time value.

If kernels are identical, there should be only 1 minima point such as 90 kernels to gtx 1080 and 10 kernels to gtx1050, per second. If there are many different kernels, then they could become other variables for the solver.

Solver includes some math you can do maybe. I'll add only a solverless version:

- give them their own queues of kernels
- have them get kernels one at a time (finishes, gets a new )
- check size of those queues.

  Empty queue = 1.0 performance. 
  Full queue = 0.0 performance

continue optimizing by "produce"ing a kernel to 1 queue at a time(maybe a fixed time or quickly until one of queues is filled), by probability equal to performance, probably a normalized version which makes 0.1 0.1 equal to 0.5 0.5. Set max size of each queue to 50 to 100 for simple accuracy of performance.

In CUDA you can assign multiple "stream"s so that you can do this with multiple queues per GPU, asynchronously to each other, to increase GPU usage further. It's important to check sum of queues performance values per GPU stays in tune with its real performance.

Since you run millions of kernels, you can have queues with thousands of kernels to make a better performance measurement. Just 5 max size of a queue may not be very good to share a few kernels.

Maybe you can make queue max sizes adapting to their attached GPU performances. Starting with just 5 max size, increasing to thousands on fastest GPUs so that performance can be measured like 0.5444533 instead of just 0.5.

When last kernel is enqueued, all remaining number of elements in queues should be equal to or near their own GPU performances and expected to finish at the same time.

(untested)